# Javascript map native object methods

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In Python, you can something like this:

```
>>> list(map(str.upper, ['foo','bar']))
['FOO', 'BAR']
```

I would like to be able to do something similar in javascript:

I've tried the following in Chrome using the native map implementation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ):

```
['foo','bar'].map(String.prototype.toUpperCase)

['foo','bar'].map(String.prototype.toUpperCase.call)
```

Why doesn't call work?
Is there any elegant way to do this or must I wrap toUpperCase in a callback function?
Thx

Comment: `toUpperCase.call` doesn't work because `call` is resolved against `Function.prototype` and so is not related to `toUpperCase`.  It looks at `this` to figure out which method is being called, and the way `map` invokes the function, `this` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers support this ([although it is a recent addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```
var a = ['foo','bar'];
var b = a.map(String.toUpperCase);

alert(b[1]);
```

or even

```
var a = ['foo','bar'].map(String.toUpperCase);
alert(a[0]);
```

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/xPsba/

Comment: That works in firefox 4 but not in chrome 7 on mac. Guess I'll have to wrap it in a function :)

Comment: This won't work on other browser than Firefox because `String.toUpperCase` is a *Mozilla-extension*, not part of the ECMAScript Standard (note that can be wrongly confused with `String.prototype.toUpperCase`), they call those "static" methods "Array and String Generics" and I don't really think other implementors will include them....

Comment: your JSFiddle snippet is using **MooTools**, put [No Library](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xPsba/2/) and try on other browsers. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
['foo','bar'].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase))
```

or for the same effect:

```
['foo','bar'].map(Function.call.bind("".toUpperCase))
```

JavaScript's treatment of `this` is a bad trip.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `String.prototype.toUpperCase` runs on `this` (Context) object but `map` function can't set the array element as context. It passes it as an argument. A workaround would be

```
['foo','bar'].map(function(k) { return String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(k) });
```

Comment: even better is to skip the prototype part altogether and use it as `['foo','bar'].map(String.toUpperCase);` which runs in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

You're all missing the point. :-)

We want to call a *method* (not a function) on all elements of an array.  You can use `map`:

```
a.map(function(x){x.frob()})
```

but that's too much typing.  We want to say:

```
a.mapm(A.frob)
```

where `A` is the class of the elements of `a` and `mapm` is a new `Array` method that calls its argument method on each element of `this` (array `a` in this case).  You could define `mapm` thus:

```
Array.prototype.mapm = function (method)
{
    return this.map(function (x) { return method.apply(x) } )
};
```

and call it thus:

```
["a", "b", "c"].mapm("".toUpperCase)    ==>     ["A", "B", "C"]
```

The only problem is that you've added a new element, `mapm` to every array, though it's ignored by most `Array` methods, e.g. `length` and `map`.

Comment: +1 for understanding the point. Of course, in cases where your code will need to play nicely with other code, modifying Array's prototype is risky, so maybe a slight rework to allow something like:`a.map(method("toUpperCase")); function method(m){return function(x){return x[m]();}}` Plus, a minor enhancement could also allow you to pass some parameters for the method via `method`

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
function map(arr, fn){
    var i = 0, len = arr.length, ret = [];
    while(i < len){
        ret[i] = fn(arr[i++]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And to use it:

```
var result = map(['foo', 'bar'], function(item) {
    return item.toUpperCase();
});

console.log ( result ); // => ['FOO', 'BAR']
```

Comment: Do you have any example usage? I would rather use the native map function though.

Comment: It is not broadly available yet

Comment: a for loop would be a lot more simpler :p

Comment: Not sure `for` is any simpler, but clearly more conventional ;)

Comment: The OP didn't want a re-implementation of the native map method.  Your code won't solve his problem which is mapping a _method_ over an array.

Comment: @DenisHowe, at the time of the answer there were no native map functions in most browsers